# PHP write get variables to .txt file not working, no errors

Tags: php, json, get

I am using PHP to capture GET variables then write them to a text (.txt) file where I can later open the file and get the variables.

All of my code is listed below, it will not write to file and no errors are giving, thanks for reading.

```
<?php

//the link is (your domain)/writefile.php?user=$user&password=$pass

$theuser = $_GET["user"];
$thepassword = $_GET["password"];
$full = $theuser . ':' . $thepassword;
echo htmlentities($full); //Potential XSS
$file = 'crackedaccs.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= "$full \n";
file_put_contents($file, $current, LOCK_EX);

?>
```

Comment: make sure these are at the top of your php page: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: have php got writing writes in the current dir?  If php runs as www-data, you'll probably need to put chmod 666 on the file, creating it first, if not, you have to make the folder chmod 777.

Comment: your code runs fine (albeit it's not the most perfect code in the world), see comment above: check file permissions!

Comment: by the way, if you have multiple concurrent http queries your file won't be reliable...

Comment: you might consider looking into using sqlite for this kind of thing.

Comment: I had to chmood 777 the folder! thanks it worked.